# Android app name not changed in status bar when launching in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, launch

**The Situation:**

- I decided to change my app's name, so I changed the package name, the
  strings.xml, and the manifest file.
- also I searched and replaced it in all the project's files.
- but when I launch the app on eclipse I get "Launching OldAppName" pm 
  the bottom right corner.

**The First Offers:**
people here offered me things I already tried

**My Failed Attempts:**
I tried copying the files (in res, src) to a new project, but that didn't help

**My Succesful Attemps:**
I copied the entire directory, and opened it in another computer, and then it showed the right name

**My Remaining Question:**
where could that value be? and why does it still show it there?

Comment: did u check string.xml ?

Comment: Did you remove the app and re-install ?

Comment: There is an app name in the string.xml file as well probably hasn't been changed

Comment: nope, i replaced all the text inside all files, including strings.xml

Comment: and i removed it and reinstalled, and even used a different device to test it on

Comment: did you check the project properties ? (project name for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally!! found the file responsible**

there was a file called ***OldAppName*.launch**

it is located in **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches**

also stuff on:

**/home/amir/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring/.refactorings**

might be connected

thanks to the guys who tried helping, hope this will help somebody else :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was puzzled by this too. i wonder if not fixing this has any consequences. its just different name on eclipse status bar when launching.

Comment: glad to help :) maybe not fixing it would have been fine, but I like things to be organized

Answer (score 7):

I solved it like this:

Eclipse -> Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings,

in the window, select the "Launch configuration" for your project,
if it has a wrong name, delete it.

Next time you launch your project, the Eclipse will ask whether to launch it as an Android Application or something else. Choose "Android Application".

--> a new launch configuration with the correct name will be created.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me - so simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my two cents.

Your dealing with the name of the debug configuration. Click the arrow near the debug button and select "Debug Config". Select the outstanding configuration and at the very top of the dialogue you can rename the configuration, or you can delete it and make a new one.

I would suggest this rather than deleting Eclipses configuration file directly.

Comment: This works for me, just go to Debug Configuration and change the name on the top right and press Apply. 

By the way, if you cannot change a name due to it's already exists. Find it in Android JUnit Test or other category.

Answer (score 0):

Just change value of app_name in string.xml file and then right click on project folder and rename it, that's all

Comment: doesn't work for me, since this is not what's causing the problem. note that I had written in the description that I replaced all occurences of the old app name in the project's folder

Answer (score 0):

Go to `res -> values -> strings.xml -> appname`, change name of the app there.

No go to Android Manifest and check if it looks like this:

```
<application

    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    .......................
>
```

If `android:label="@string/app_name"` is changed to `android:label="MyApp"`, than change it to one shown above. Your problem should be solved.

Comment: clean your project in eclipse and also uninstall it from your test devices.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to solve this is to

**Run --> Run Configurations**

i am adding snapshot of it

[image]

i have added string to explain. You just need to give your desired name.
it will create new
**newAppName.launch** inside **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches**

Reference : 
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm